# Adding 1 to value in textbox

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function that I am creating. It is take a time (mm:ss) inputted by a user and then being displayed on a php page.

One of the problems that I, for some reason, cannot seem to work through is getting the minutes to increase by x when seconds is greater than 60.

For example, if the user enters in a run time of `01:53` and a penalty time of `00:25`, the output is `01:18`, when it really should be `02:18`.

I created an if statement with the condition being if seconds is great than 60, to increment the minute by 1.

This is the function that I have so far. Also, is it easier to handle the input of time this way, or would it be easier and more efficient to handle time using the time() function?

```js
function dfbcalc() {

  var dfbrun = document.getElementById("dfb_run").value;
  var dfbpen = document.getElementById("dfb_pen").value;

  var splitdfbrun = dfbrun.split(':');
  var splitdfbpen = dfbpen.split(':');

  var dfbmin;
  var dfbsec;
  var dfbtot;

  <!-- DFB Time input -->
  dfbmin = parseInt(splitdfbrun[0]) + parseInt(splitdfbpen[0])
  dfbmin = dfbmin % 60;

  dfbsec = parseInt(splitdfbrun[1]) + parseInt(splitdfbpen[1])
  dfbsec = dfbsec % 60;

  if (dfbsec < 10) {
    dfbsec = '0' + dfbsec;
  }

  if (dfbsec > 60) {
    dfbmin = dfbmin + 1;
  }

  alert(+dfbmin + ':' + dfbsec)
  dfbtot = '0' + dfbmin + ':' + dfbsec;
  document.getElementById("dfb_com").value = dfbtot;
}
```

```js
  var dfbrun = "01:53"
  var dfbpen = "00:25"

  var splitdfbrun = dfbrun.split(':');
  var splitdfbpen = dfbpen.split(':');

  var dfbmin;
  var dfbsec;
  var dfbtot;

  <!-- DFB Time input -->
  dfbmin = parseInt(splitdfbrun[0]) + parseInt(splitdfbpen[0])
  dfbmin = dfbmin % 60;

  dfbsec = parseInt(splitdfbrun[1]) + parseInt(splitdfbpen[1])
  dfbsec = dfbsec % 60;

  if (dfbsec < 10) {
    dfbsec = '0' + dfbsec;
  }

  if (dfbsec > 60) {
    dfbmin = dfbmin + 1;
  }

  document.write(+dfbmin + ':' + dfbsec+"<br/>")
  dfbtot = '0' + dfbmin + ':' + dfbsec;
  document.write(dfbtot);
```

Comment: Well how can it be greater than 60?

Comment: @epascarello 53 seconds plus 25 are 78 seconds.

Comment: @reporter Yeah but `dfbsec = dfbsec % 60;` nullifies your argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your order of operation. You're cutting the value off before checking how many minutes to add.

```
  dfbmin = parseInt(splitdfbrun[0]) + parseInt(splitdfbpen[0])
  dfbmin = dfbmin % 60;

  dfbsec = parseInt(splitdfbrun[1]) + parseInt(splitdfbpen[1])

  // Update Minutes
  if (dfbsec >= 60) {
    dfbmin = dfbmin + 1;
  }

  // Update seconds
  dfbsec = dfbsec % 60;

  if (dfbsec < 10) {
    dfbsec = '0' + dfbsec;
  }
```

Comment: Ok, I see it now. I was going crazy there for a little while trying to figure out what the heck I was doing wrong. Haha. When it was just a simple order of operation. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert all to seconds and back to minutes and seconds.
That makes it easier to grasp the order.

```js
function pad(num) {
  return ("0"+num).slice(-2);
}
function getTot(dfbrun,dfbpen) {
  var splitdfbrun = dfbrun.split(':');
  var splitdfbpen = dfbpen.split(':');

  var dfbmin;
  var dfbsec;

  <!-- DFB Time input -->

  dfbmin = parseInt(splitdfbrun[0],10) + parseInt(splitdfbpen[0],10);
  dfbsec = dfbmin * 60;

  dfbsec += parseInt(splitdfbrun[1],10) + parseInt(splitdfbpen[1],10);

  dfbmin = Math.floor(dfbsec / 60);
  dfbsec = dfbsec - dfbmin * 60;

  return  pad(dfbmin) + ':' + pad(dfbsec);
}

var dfbrun = "01:53"
var dfbpen = "00:25"
  
document.write(getTot(dfbrun,dfbpen));
```